# Mostrar valor do BD em Dropdown Box

Tags: php, html, dropdown

Tenho no meu banco de dados um valor pra nível de usuário e gostaria de poder modificar ele na alteração. Preciso de ao abrir a pagina carregar o nível do usuário logado:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Nivel de Usuário</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="">
        <option value="2">Usuário Comum</option>
        <option value="1">Administrador</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Na minha session eu já tenho o ID do usuário e já fiz o `select`, só preciso de pegar esse nível (do usuário selecionado), como por exemplo "1" e, ao abrir a pagina, mostrar a opção `<option value="1">Administrador</option>`.

A questão de validação de usuário pra cada área é tranquila pra fazer. A minha duvida no momento é somente essa em relação ao HTML do Dropdown com PHP.

Desde já agradeço a todos e a todas as respostas!

Comment: vc quer aplicar o `selected` na option? esses valores são fixos ou vem do banco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Nivel de Usuário</label>
    <select class="form-control" disabled="true">
        <option value="2" <?php if ($$row_listaMe['nivel'] == 2){echo "selected";}; ?>>Usuário Comum</option>
        <option value="1" <?php if ($row_listaMe['nivel'] == 1){echo "selected";}; ?>>Administrador</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Você não tinha falado se as options eram fixas ou não, se conseguiu resolver ta valendo :). Se as opções aumentarem muito pense em guardar no banco, porque dessa forma vc vai precisar de um if para cada option, imagine agora com 10 options ou mais.

Comment: @rray verdade, isso é naverdade o que vou passar mais pra frente na construção deste site. Devo precisar de um select com aproximadamente 20/25 options. Nesse caso vou ver como faço e talvez irei abrir outro tópico xD
Muito obrigado rray, novamente!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode verificar no looping que faz para adicionar as opções se o `ID` é igual ao `ID` do nível do usuário logado

```
$nivelUsuarioLogado = 2;

$niveis = array(
    1=>'Administrador',
    2=>'Usuário Comum'
);

echo '<div class="form-group">';
    echo '<label>Nivel de Usuário</label>';
    echo '<select class="form-control" name="">';
        foreach($niveis as $key => $value){
            $selected = ($nivelUsuarioLogado == $key) ? true : false;

            echo '<option value="'.$key.'" '.(($selected) ? 'selected="selected"' : '').'>';
                echo $value;
            echo '</option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode simplicar a verificação com do valor que deve ter o selected com printf.

```
<select name="nivel">
   <?php
       foreach($niveis as $item){
          $select = $item['id'] == $nivel_session ? $select = 'selected = "selected"' : "";
          printf('<option value="%d">%s</option>'. $item['id'], $item['nivel_descricao']);
       }
   ?>
</select>
```

Comment: não entendi exatamente. de onde vem esse 'nivel_descricao'? eu não possuo no banco de dados os nomes, somente numeros 1 e 2 que indicam esses niveis @rray

Comment: @lucas caso seja um array do banco de dados

Comment: eu consegui resolver aqui a partir de um if simples. não tinha pensado nisso. fiquei um tempão quebrando a cabeça até conseguir resolver. vou publicar aqui embaixo a solução. De qualquer forma, muito obrigado pela resposta, ela me deu uma luz pra conseguir resolver!